# Docker container IO performance

Tags: database, virtualization, docker

I am trying to investigate the IO performance overhead of docker so I created a mysql docker container on a specific machine and I ran the sysbench mysql benchmark to measure IO performance. Sysbench basically executes some read/write transactions over a period of time and then outputs the number of completed transactions and the transactions/second rate.

When I run the benchmark on the native machine, I get a 779.5 transactions per second. When I run the benchmark in a mysql container, I get  336 transactions/second. Almost half the number of transactions per second. Is this a normal performance overhead of docker? This is a huge disadvantage for running the database in a container in production systems, especially for IO/database intensive applications

Comment: This may be a question better posed on serverfault.

Comment: See http://www.enterprisetech.com/2014/08/18/ibm-techies-pit-docker-kvm-bare-metal/
Docker should be on par with bare metal under most conditions, except for networking.

Comment: What kind of transactions are you running? Caching might be a factor here.

Answer (score 6):

Are you using a Docker volume for the database files?  By default, file writes inside the container will be made to the copy-on-write filesystem, which will be inefficient for database files.  Using a volume will mean you can write directly to the host filesystem.